# HTML Sanitizer after upgrade hybris

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp, upgrade, sap-commerce-cloud

I just updated Hybris to version 2105. It happens that the `ycommerce:sanitizeHTML("some string")` method in JSP raises this exception:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class de.hybris.platform.acceleratorservices.util.HtmlSanitizerPolicyProviderSan

I don't know if any library will have to be changed. Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `owasp-java-html-sanitizer-xxxx.jar` in your custom extension, remove those. The problem was, in my case because I have different version of `owasp-java-html-sanitizer-xxxx.jar` in my custom extension with ootb hybris.